# Is it possible to import an SQL file?

Tags: database, importing-exporting

I have an SQL database created from another application and I would like to add it to my existing Drupal 8 site. I didn't find a way to do so.

I came across the Data module, but I have no idea how to use it and I don't find any documentation.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You mean into the database as non Drupal tables (no name collisions)? Yes.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Yes, of course you can have a database from another application on your server. Yes, you can use that database directly from Drupal, yes, you can add the tables from that database to your Drupal database. But in all these cases you're still going to need code to actually USE that data within the Drupal framework.

Answer (score 1):

For usage on Data module please check external documentation https://www.drupal.org/node/2180593

There is another drupal 8 stable module that can be helpful to achieve the results.
You can import the custom sql table into the drupal DB directly and can be used in Drupal Views directly.

https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to import.

[Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate/) is the module suite of choice. See [Drupal 8 external content migration translation problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291703/drupal-8-external-content-migration-translation-problem) for a multilingual setup ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to add tables with data on them. I'll check your recommended module